# Write multiple rewrites in .htaccess - codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my code for .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost/h [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

I tried to execute multiple rules, but for the first one it works correctly(without index.php) and second one (removing www.) executes with extra "?" mark. 
My URL(without www.) is: http://localhost/h/home/sub_cat_service/8 and
Resultant URL(adding with www.) is: http://localhost/h/?home/sub_cat_service/8

How i shall remove "?" mark from the URL?
    thanks

Comment: You have to alter hosts file on you OS to allow `www` subdomain be reachable.